# cleaning datasources

Tags: sql, mysql, database, excel, filemaker

I'm project managing a development that's pulling data from all kinds of data sources (SQL MySQL, Filemaker, excel) before installing into a new database structure with a record base through 10 years. Obviously I need to clean all this before exporting, and am wondering if there are any apps that can simplify this process for me, or any guides that I can follow.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time and like Tom do it in SQl Server using DTS or SSIS depending on the version of the final database.

Some things I strongly recommend:

Archive all files received before you process them especially if you are getting this data from outside sources, you may have to research old imports and go back to the raw data. After the archive is successful, copy the file to the processing location.

For large files especially, it is helpful to get some sort of flag file that is only copied after the other file is completed or even better whcich contains the number of records in the file. This can help prevent problems from corrupted or incomplete files.

Keep a log of number of records and start failing your jobs if the file size or number of records is suspect. Put in a method to process anyway if you find the change is correct. Sometimes they really did mean to cut the file in half but most of the time they didn't.

If possible get column headers in the file. You would be amazed at how often data sources change the columns, column names or order of the columns without advance warning and break imports. It is easier to check this before processing data if you have column headers.

Never import directly to a production table. Always better to use a staging table where you can check and clean data before putting it into prod.

Log each step of your process, so you can easily find what caused a failure.

If you are cleaning lots of files consider creating functions to do specific types of cleaning (phone number formatting for instance) then you can use the same function in multiple imports.

Excel files are evil. Look for places where leading zeros have been stripped in the import process.

I write my processes so I can run them as a test with a rollback at the end. Much better to do this than realize your dev data is so hopelessly messed up that you can't even do a valid test to be sure everything can be moved to prod.

Never do a new import on prod without doing it on dev first. Eyeball the records directly when you are starting a new import (not all of them if it is a large file of course, but a good sampling). If you think you should get 20 columns and it imports the first time as 21 columns, look at the records in that last column, many times that means the tab delimited file had a tab somewhere in the data and the column data is off for that record.

Don't assume the data is correct, check it first. I've had first names in the last name column, phones in the zip code column etc.

Check for invalid characters, string data where there should just be numbers etc.

Any time it is possible, get the identifier from the people providing the data. Put this in a table that links to your identifier. This will save you from much duplication of records becuase the last name changed or the address changed.

There's lots more but this should get you started on thinking about building processes to protect your company's data by not importing bad stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I work mostly with Microsoft SQL Server, so that's where my expertise is, but SSIS can connect to a pretty big variety of data sources and is very good for ETL work. You can use it even if none of your data sources are actually MS SQL Server. That said, if you're not using MS SQL Server there is probably something out there that's better for this.

To provide a really good answer one would need to have a complete list of your data sources and destination(s) as well as any special tasks which you might need to complete along with any requirements for running the conversion (is it a one-time deal or do you need to be able to schedule it?)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about tools, but your going to have to deal with:

- synchronizing generated keys
- synchronizing/normalizing data formats (e.g. different date formats)
- synchronizing record structures.
- orphan records

If the data is running/being updated while you're developing this process or moving data you're also going to need to capture the updates. When I've had to do this sort of thing in the past the best, not so great answer I had was to develop a set of scripts that ran in multiple iterations, so that I could develop and test the process iteratively before I moved any of the data. I found it helpful to have a script (I used a schema and an ant script, but it could be anything) that could clean/rebuild the destination database. It's also likely that you'll need to have some way of recording dirty/mismatched data.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations I personally have found Emacs and Python mighty useful but, I guess, any text editor with good searching capabilities and a language with powerful string manipulation features should do the job.  I first convert the data into flat text files and then

1. Eyeball either the whole data set or a representative true random sample of the data.
2. Based on that make conjectures about different columns ("doesn't allow nulls", "contains only values 'Y' and 'N'", "'start date' always precede 'end date'", etc.).
3. Write scripts to check the conjectures.

Obviously this kind method tends to focus on one table at a time and therefore only complements the checks made after uploading the data into a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

One trick that comes in useful for me with this, is to find a way for each type of data source to output a single column plus unique identifier at a time in tab delimited form say, so that you can clean it up using text tools (sed, awk, orTextMate's grep search), and then re-import it / update the (copy of!) original source.

It then becomes much quicker to clean up multiple sources, as you can re-use tools across them (e.g. capitalising last names - McKay, O'Leary o'Neil, Da Silva, Von Braun, etc., fixing date formats, trimming whitespace) and to some extent automate the process (depending on the source).